# i am unable to run server in pgadmin 4 v4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have tried reinstalling PostgreSQL 12 and pgadmin many times and also tried installing different versions of them. still after doing this, I was not able to run server

[when I click the ">" arrow in the server, the other files are not listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1xrt.png)

[instead I am getting blank like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0zNM.png)

while installing postgresql I also got [problem running post-install step database cluster initialization failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IQ18.png) error. whether this is affecting pgadmin, if so how to solve it?

Comment: So what happens if you add a server? Those entries define _connections_ to a Postgres server. You don't use them to "start a server"

Answer (score 0):

Try right-click the server which has ">" arrow left to it.  Pop up will show up and you should be able to select "create".  It opens a dialog to create a connection configuration.

Comment: I tried this also, but when I click It I got the same

Answer (score 0):

And also when i try to create new server I get a error like this
Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432
 [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxHd7.png)